# Is it possible to change the scale of the sp unit

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fonts

In my XML I can set textSize="18sp". Is it possible to change the scale of the sp unit which would affect all sp sizes but not affect dp sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible. It was meant to be a user setting but it hasn't been exposed in the UI so far.